# Lotus Notes slow startup if lots of files are placed in the data/html folder

Tags: html, xpages, offline, lotus

I have a non-responsive problem with my Lotus Notes client when I placed a lot of files in the data/html folder.

The files are actually map tiles that allow offline maps to be shown to users.
There are a lot of folders and files in there, around 1 million in total.
My XPages reference the files to display offline maps.

If I start Notes from boot, it seems to scan the folder so intensely that it becomes unresponsive and takes around 3 mins to come back to me.
This is on the live system, however on my development laptop this does not occur.

Has anyone seen this before?

What could be scanning the data/html folders and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely possibility is virus scanning software. Usually it's best to skip anything under `data`, because NSFs will constantly be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul. AV isn't running any CPU. It would appear  it's all to do with opening databases via links. If I open a database using File -> Open Application, the problem doesn't exist and it opens quickly. There's a fix associated with a TCP Offload patch which I'm going to try....

Comment: Solved. We were opening a database from its notesID via a menu type database. This was mainly due to code which works out whether a local or server copy of the database exists before opening the link. This causes Lotus Notes to search all folders to find the database even down several folders to a place where it shouldn't really be going. We're now naming the database when we open it. An added bonus is that it's now quicker than ever to startup.